# Get the ClickOnce query parameters in the currently running instance of the application

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce

I have a WPF app which uses **ClickOnce** deployment. It has some query parameters when launched, which we get through `ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri`. This method worked just fine, but now the app is single instance. We handle the "single instance" by implementing `WindowsFormsApplicationBase` from  `Microsoft.VisualBasic` dll.

So when a new instance of an app is launched I should get the query parameters and and handle them in the already running app. My problem is that I can't get the query params when launching app using click once.

I'm trying to get the parameter by overriding the `OnStartupNextInstance` of the  `WindowsFormsApplicationBase` class, like this:

```
protected override void OnStartupNextInstance(StartupNextInstanceEventArgs eventArgs)
 {
    var queryString = eventArgs.CommandLine;
    //handle queryStringParams
 }
```

`eventArgs.CommandLine` has 0 elements when launched using **ClickOnce**, but it does have elements when I launch my app through command line, like this:

```
myApp.exe "param1=someValue&param2=someOtherValue"
```

Also if I try to get them through `ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri` it gives me the params of the currently running app (obviously).

Comment: Did you try AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData[0]?

Comment: @mm8 unfortunately the same as `ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri` - data of the currently running instance

Comment: Of course...how is the currently running instance supposed to know the command line arguments or anything else about a different instance??

Comment: @mm8 it does catch the command line params (if launched from cmd) in the `StartupNextInstanceEventArgs eventArgs`. But it doesn't catch any args when launched through `.application` (ClickOnce)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem, although not so straight forward as i expected. As I already explained in my question, the only place the already running app can catch the cmd params of a new launched instance is the override of the `OnStartupNextInstance(StartupNextInstanceEventArgs eventArgs)`. Command parameters will be available in the `eventArgs` argument, but not the parameters the new instance received from the ClickOnce launch link.

**The solution i used:**
I left the `OnStartupNextInstance(StartupNextInstanceEventArgs eventArgs)`, which is in a separate class called `SingleInstanceManager` which inherits from `WindowsFormsApplicationBase` intact, (after I little while i understood that i had no chance of getting `ClickOnce` parameters here).

Instead I modified the `void static Main(string[] args)` method of the `App.xaml.cs`. Main modifications:

1. I got the `ActivationUri` through
   `ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri`;
2. Made a string out of the `Query` propery of the `ActivationUri`;
3. Added that string to the `args` parameter;
4. Passed that parameter to the `SingleInstanceManager` class described
   above.

The entire solution finally looks like this:

```
        [STAThread]
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;

            //Creating SingleInstaceManager
            SingleInstanceManager manager = new SingleInstanceManager();

            //Uncommend the following if statement if you want to debug App's Main method
            //if (!System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            //{
            //    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
            //}

            try
            {
                if (ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri != null)
                {
                    var query = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri?.Query;

                    var cmdParams = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(query)
                        ? new NameValueCollection(0)
                        : HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(query);

                    var updatedArgs = args.ToList();
                    updatedArgs.Add(cmdParams.ToString());
                    args = updatedArgs.ToArray();
                }
            }

            //Empty catch to ignore the annoying InvalidDeploymentException while debuging; 
            catch (InvalidDeploymentException)
            { }

            //Passing parameters to the SingleInstaceManager
            manager.Run(args);
        }
```

**Note:**

This solution is not WPF specific only, and it should work for any kind of desktop app, as long as it has an entry point in which you can get the `ActivationUri`. Hope this will help someone.

Comment: Thank you Alex, you saved my day! But I had  to read arguments using ActivationData, instead of ActivationUri:
string[] inputArgs = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData;
if (inputArgs != null && inputArgs.Length > 0) {
  string args = inputArgs[0];
  args = args.Split(new char[] { ',' });
}